# How to implement autocomplete functionality in react-redux architecture?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, autocomplete

I am following the ***Redux architecture*** in my ongoing React project. Previously I had used the ***auto-complete feature*** in the project, but it takes more time to search the data.

**Is there any other way to implement the Autocomplete functionality in React-Redux environment?**. Any other library present over there that can help with this?

Here is the code snippet for the above issue.

```
const renderInput = inputProps => {
const { input,autoFocus, value, ref, ...other } = inputProps;
return (
  <div>
 <TextField
    autoFocus={autoFocus}
    value={value}
    inputRef={ref}
    InputProps={{
      ...other,
       }}
  />
</div>
return (
  <MenuItem
    selected={isHighlighted}
    component="div"
    onClick={selectSuggestion}
    onKeyPress={e => {
      if (e.key === keys.ENTER) {
        selectSuggestion();
      }
    }}
  >
    <div>
      {map(parts, (part, index) => {
        return part.highlight ? (
          <span key={index} style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>
            {part.text}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <strong key={index}>{part.text}</strong>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </MenuItem>
);
};
```

Comment: This is nicely written autocomplete with accessibility and it was easy to integrate with redux https://github.com/moroshko/react-autowhatever

Comment: https://github.com/ItsMrAkhil/doctalk-test/blob/debounce/app/containers/HomePage/index.js
Have a look at this file. It's a very easy approach.